# Comparing, matching and combining columns of data

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I need some help matching data and combining it. I currently have four columns of data in an Excel sheet, similar to the following:

```
Column:     1       2      3      4

            U       3      A      0
            W       6      B      0
            R       1      C      0
            T       9      D      0
            ...     ...    ...    ...
```

Column two is a data value that corresponds to the letter in column one. What I need to do is compare column 3 with column 1 and whenever it matches copy the corresponding value from column 2 to column 4.

You might ask why don't I do this manually ? I have a spreadsheet with around 100,000 rows so this really isn't an option!

I do have access to MATLAB and have the information imported, if this would be more easily completed within that environment, please let me know.

Comment: Seems like this would be straightforward with a formula?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Although, as Tim pointed out, you can do this with a simple `IF` function

Comment: you can actually do it in excell: on the first row where the value `0` (say cell D1) is write a formula similar to `=IF(A1=C1,B1,0)`  then by double-clicking on the bottom right hand corner of that cell (ie on the box that you would otherwise drag) you'll copy that formula to the 100000 rows....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @bla:

> a formula similar to `=IF(A1=C1,B1,0)`

should serve (Excel).